# How does a data merge between indexed tables work?

Tags: indexing, merge, sas

Recently I had to start working with SAS indexed tables. The problem is that trying to sort a indexed table, I could not do it, unless I deleted the Index. I understood the problem, because when sorting an Indexed table the RID from the Index changes and SAS cannot locate anymore the row.

But I cannot get to understand why a merge works perfectly, keeping the index and updating it. In a full outer join between two tables the rows are also changed, but SAS It’s able to keep the Index. I thought about some possibilities like when making the merge, as they are two sorted tables, when inserting a row it only has to add 1 to the RIDS bellow. But I would like to know if it is really like this.

Sorry for my explanation, making myself clear is not my stronger gift.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting

```
options msglevel = i;
```

before running your code - SAS will then print diagnostic messages in the log showing exactly when it is and isn't using indexes, and when they are created or removed.

If you want a more specific answer, please post some specific code.